# SQL query not selecting records

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to select * records. The problem is some only have values ('MNT', 'NPT', 'OM') for **attrib_type 1-3** in this case. Attribute types 4 & 5 do not exist in the older records therefore there are 4500 records that are not being selected. I would like to be able to select ALL records even where there is no **attrib_type 4 & 5** value.

The SQL I have tried is below

```
SELECT
   central_site.site_code,
   central_site.site_name,
   ward.ward_name,
   area.area_name,
   feature_type.feature_type_code,
   feature_type.feature_type_name,
   feature.feat_cent_east,
   feature.feat_cent_north,
   feat_measurement.feature_quantity,
   feat_attrib_type.attrib_value_code,
   feat_attrib_type_2.attrib_value_code,
   feat_attrib_type_3.attrib_value_code,
   feat_attrib_type_4.attrib_value_code,
   feat_attrib_type_5.attrib_value_code
FROM
   area,
   central_site,
   feat_attrib_type,
   feat_attrib_type feat_attrib_type_2,
   feat_attrib_type feat_attrib_type_3,
   feat_attrib_type feat_attrib_type_4,
   feat_attrib_type feat_attrib_type_5,
   feat_measurement,
   feature,
   feature_type,
   site,
   ward
WHERE
   central_site.site_code = site.site_code AND
   site.site_code = feature.site_code AND
   ward.ward_code = feature.ward_code AND
   area.area_code = feature.area_code AND
   feature_type.feature_type_code = feature.feature_type_code AND
   feature.site_code = feat_attrib_type.site_code AND
   feature.plot_number = feat_attrib_type.plot_number AND
   (feat_attrib_type.attrib_type_code = 'MNT' OR feat_attrib_type.attrib_type_code IS NULL) AND
   feature.site_code = feat_attrib_type_2.site_code AND
   feature.plot_number = feat_attrib_type_2.plot_number AND
   (feat_attrib_type_2.attrib_type_code = 'NPT' OR feat_attrib_type_2.attrib_type_code IS NULL) AND
   feature.site_code = feat_measurement.site_code AND
   feature.plot_number = feat_measurement.plot_number AND
   (feat_measurement.measurement_code = 'NSNP' OR feat_measurement.measurement_code IS NULL) AND
   feature.site_code = feat_attrib_type_3.site_code AND
   feature.plot_number = feat_attrib_type_3.plot_number AND
   (feat_attrib_type_3.attrib_type_code = 'OM' OR feat_attrib_type_3.attrib_type_code IS NULL) AND
   feature.site_code = feat_attrib_type_4.site_code AND
   feature.plot_number = feat_attrib_type_4.plot_number AND
   (feat_attrib_type_4.attrib_type_code = 'PMNT' OR feat_attrib_type_4.attrib_type_code IS NULL) AND
   feature.site_code = feat_attrib_type_5.site_code AND
   feature.plot_number = feat_attrib_type_5.plot_number AND
   (feat_attrib_type_5.attrib_type_code = 'WMNT' OR feat_attrib_type_5.attrib_type_code IS NULL)
ORDER BY
   central_site.site_code ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mihai said, use a LEFT JOIN on feat_attrib_type_4 and feat_attrib_type_5.  Either old style (as you have) or ANSI joins style would work.  For the former add (+) after every reference to a column in the where clause from those two aliases.  For the latter, convert the statement to ANSI join syntax and add LEFT before the word JOIN for those two tables.

Comment: Please do not suggest to use the Oracle proprietary syntax for outer joins. for one because we don't know which DBMS Chris is using. And secondly because even Oracle suggests to stop using it.

Comment: I agree and personally prefer ANSI syntax as well, but if the OP is on Oracle sometimes the expediency of adding (+) beats converting the syntax to ANSI.  I'll leave that for the OP to decide.  Thank you for pointing out that even Oracle deprecates it as that should help with the decision.

Answer (score 1):

What DBMS are you using? The syntax will differ slightly between systems. but the general principle remains the same: you're going to have to specify that nuance on the join itself. There are four (common) kinds of joins.

- INNER JOIN: The default join, where rows that cannot be matched are thrown out.
- LEFT OUTER JOIN/LEFT JOIN: Rows on the table that is on the left side of the JOIN statement (i.e., the first table) that cannot be matched are returned, but those on the other table are not.
- RIGHT OUTER JOIN/RIGHT JOIN: Same as above, but the all the second table's rows are returned rather than the first.
- FULL OUTER JOIN: All rows are returned, regardless of a match.

Right now you are using the WHERE clause to specify how the joins work. That's not just inefficient, it won't work properly for anything but the simplest query.

So, for example:

```
SELECT
   central_site.site_code,
   central_site.site_name,
   ward.ward_name,
   area.area_name,
   feature_type.feature_type_code,
   feature_type.feature_type_name,
   feature.feat_cent_east,
   feature.feat_cent_north,
   feat_measurement.feature_quantity,
   feat_attrib_type.attrib_value_code,
   feat_attrib_type_2.attrib_value_code,
   feat_attrib_type_3.attrib_value_code,
   feat_attrib_type_4.attrib_value_code,
   feat_attrib_type_5.attrib_value_code
FROM
   feature
   INNER JOIN site ON feature.site_code = site.site_code
   INNER JOIN ward ON feature.ward_code = ward.ward_code
   INNER JOIN area ON feature.area_code = area.area_code
   INNER JOIN central_site ON central_site.site_code = site.site_code
   INNER JOIN feature_type ON feature_type.feature_type_code = feature.feature_type_code
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN feat_attrib_type 
        ON feature.site_code = feat_attrib_type.site_code
        AND feature.plot_number = feat_attrib_type.plot_number 
        AND (feat_attrib_type.attrib_type_code = 'MNT' OR feat_attrib_type.attrib_type_code IS NULL)
```

Et cetera. Also, looking at your query, why don't you try looking into using a PIVOT instead of joining on the same table 5 times?